# Quartz.net scheduler and IStatefulJob

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am wondering if I am understanding this right.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/

> IStatefulJob instances follow slightly
>   different rules from regular IJob
>   instances. The key difference is that
>   their associated JobDataMap is
>   re-persisted after every execution of
>   the job, thus preserving state for the
>   next execution. The other difference
>   is that stateful jobs are not allowed
>   to Execute concurrently, which means
>   new triggers that occur before the
>   completion of the IJob.Execute method
>   will be delayed.

Does this mean all triggers will be delayed until another trigger is done? If so how can I make it so only the same triggers will not fire until the previous trigger is done.

Say I have trigger A that fires every min but for some reason it is slow and takes a minute and half to execute. If I just use a plan IJob the next one would fire and I don't want this. I want to halt trigger A from fireing again until it is done.

However at the same time I have trigger B that fires every minute as well. It is going normal speed and finishes every minutes on time. I don't want trigger B to be held up because of trigger A.

From my understanding this is what would happen if I use IStatefulJob.

Answer (score 3):

In short.. This behavior is from job's side. So regardless how many triggers you may have only single instance of given IStatefulJob (job name, job group dictates the instance id) running at a time. So there might be two instance of same job type, but no same-named jobs (name, group) if job implements IStatefulJob.

If trigger misses its fire time because of this, the misfire instructions come into play. A trigger that misses its next fire because the earlier invocation is still running decides what to do based on its misfire instruction (see API and tutorial).

With plain IJob you have no guarantees about how many jobs will be running at the same time if you have multiple triggers for it and/or misfires are happening. IJob is just contract interface for invoking the job. Quartz.NET 2.0 will split IStatefulJob combined behavior to two separate attributes: DisallowConcurrentExecution and PersistJobDataAfterExecution.

So you could combine same job type (IStatefulJobs) with two definitions (different job names) and triggers with applicable misfire instructions.

Comment: @Marko Lahma- So your saying even if I use a IJob that only one IJob with the same name will fire?

Comment: No, this only applies to IStatefulJob. I edited the answer a bit to hopefully make it a bit more clear.

Comment: @Marko Lahma - Do they all default to the same group? I just gave them job names with no job group name.

Comment: Yes, they default to the same group. You can browse the source @ https://fisheye3.atlassian.com/browse/quartznet/ . It's forthcoming 2.0 but the basic behavior is the same.

Comment: @Marko Lahma - so if I change them to have all their own groups problem should be solved?

Comment: Own name is enough. They can be in same group,